# No method error displaying foreign key value instead of ID in show.html & index.html ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models: user, language and role. User model holds the foreign key of language and role. User (belongs_to: language) and (belongs_to: role). Language and role (has_many: users)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :role
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users 
end
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

In **_form.html.erb** I use the following code to select the value iso_code of language and name of role.

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label t("language") %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :language_id, Language.order(:iso_code),:id,:iso_code, include_blank: false %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label t("Role") + '?' %><br>
 <%= f.collection_select :type_role_id, Role.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: false %>
</div>
```

Up to here all works fine. The user selects the value (e.g.: es) and the code saves the primary key in the database. (e.g.: 2)

The in **show.html.erb**, to show the value I used the following code:

```
<%= @user.language.iso_code %>
```

It works great!

**The issue comes when I try to do exactly the same for role**:

```
<%= @user.role.name %>
```

I get an error message:

```
NoMethodError in Users#show
<%= @user.role.name %>    

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Rails thinks name is a method instead of a field in the model role.
Why does the same syntax works for language and not for role?

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: Try changing `<%= f.collection_select :family_role_id, Role.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: false %>` to `<%= f.collection_select :role_id, Role.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: false %>` to save values in `role_id`. Then you can do `@user.role.name`.

Comment: Right now you are not correctly saving `role` to the database. Please post your parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the values in `role_id` not `type_role_id`. Change the `collection_select` to below

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label t("Role") + '?' %><br>
 <%= f.collection_select :role_id, Role.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: false %>
</div>
```

Now you can do `<%= @user.role.name %>` which gives you the name of the role for the associated user object.

***Update:***

If you don't have `role_id` in `users` table, try creating a migration to add `role_id` to `users` table or you can create migration to rename `family_role_id` to `role_id` as well.

And finally do `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thank you Pavan! It worked. I did a migration and added the column. Then changed params and show.html.erb. I cleaned the browser history and it worked fine. Thanks again for you help!